# How can I prevent Vim from centering the line under the cursor on `:edit`

Tags: command-line, buffers, cursor-movement

Each time I want to save my work while editing a text file, I enter `:write` to save the file, and `:edit` to reload the file, with the side effect of resetting the undo/redo buffer.

However, an unwanted side effect of running `:edit` is that the line under the cursor is recentered.  Can anyone tell me either (i) how to prevent `:edit` from recentering the line, or (ii) if there's a different way of resetting the undo/redo buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're expressly using `:edit` in order to reset undo information? You could follow `:help clear-undo` to do this without `:edit`; I would define a custom `:Write` command that combines both.

Comment: Re "So you're expressly using `:edit` in order to reset undo information?"  Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing.  Thanks for the suggestion; I'll try rewriting the `:we` command in my `.vimrc` file to do that instead of `:edit`.  If you'd like to put that into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Alright; thanks for clarifying. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're expressly using `:edit` in order to reset the undo information, you could follow [`:help clear-undo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#clear-undo) to do this without `:edit`.

I would define a custom `:Write` command that combines both:

```
command! -bar Write
\ write |
\ let old_undolevels = &undolevels |
\ set undolevels=-1 |
\ exe "normal a \<BS>\<Esc>" |
\ let &undolevels = old_undolevels |
\ unlet old_undolevels |
\ setlocal nomodified
```

Comment: Thanks. Only one further question: After running your `Write` command, Vim has clearly written the buffer to the file, because I can reload the file and the changes are saved; but if I run `:quit` instead, I get an "E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)" error. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: Try adding `:setlocal nomodified` at the end.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your motivation of clearing the undo information on writes is to avoid going beyond the saved buffer state when undoing many steps (`uuuu...`). I personally use a different approach: I've tweaked the `u` command to stop and beep once when reaching the saved buffer state. I need to `u` once more to go beyond.

My customization integrates with the *repeat.vim* plugin; It also requires some utility functions from my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) (it's now also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/inkarkat/ingo-library)).

```
runtime autoload/repeat.vim " Must load the plugin now so that the plugin's mappings can be overridden.
let s:undoPosition = []
function! s:StopAtSavedPosition( action )
    " Buffers of type "nofile" and "nowrite" never are 'modified', so only do
    " the check for normal buffers representing files. (Otherwise, the warning
    " annoyingly happens on every undo.)
    if ingo#buffer#IsPersisted() && ! &l:modified && s:undoPosition != ingo#record#PositionAndLocation(1)
        " We've reached the undo position where the buffer contents correspond
        " to the persisted file. Stop and beep, and only continue when undo is
        " pressed again at the same position.
        call ingo#msg#WarningMsg(a:action . ' reached saved buffer state')
        execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>\<Esc>" | " Beep.

        let s:undoPosition = ingo#record#PositionAndLocation(1)
        return 1
    else
        let s:undoPosition = []
        return 0
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> u     :<C-U>if ! &l:modifiable<Bar>execute 'normal! u'<Bar>elseif ! <SID>StopAtSavedPosition('Undo')<Bar>call repeat#wrap('u',v:count)<Bar>endif<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-R> :<C-U>if ! &l:modifiable<Bar>execute "normal! \<lt>C-R>"<Bar>elseif ! <SID>StopAtSavedPosition('Redo')<Bar>call repeat#wrap("\<Lt>C-R>",v:count)<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Comment: That is my motivation, yes.  You have an interesting approach; but when I save the buffer state, I want to clear the entire undo history, so I *can't* accidentally undo beyond that.

Comment: @HuwWalters See also this older question, which has pretty much the same root motivation as yours: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/can-i-be-notified-when-im-undoing-changes-from-the-undofile/2118 and which has several different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll let @IngoKarkat write [the answer that solves your real problem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22013/how-can-i-prevent-vim-from-centering-the-line-under-the-cursor-on-edit#comment39798_22013).

However, for the benefit of future readers, you can also achieve what was originally requested by saving the view before executing `:edit` and then restoring it afterwards:

```
:let v = winsaveview()
:edit
:call winrestview(v)
```