# How to undo all changes in current session when undofile is on?

Tags: undo-redo

Without `'undofile'`, one can hold `u` or execute `undo 0`.

With `'undofile'`, everything changed, hold `u` will undo changes made in older sessions, `undo 0` will undo the entire undo history, they became useless.

The `:earlier 2h` family command only works on certain conditions, it's not so useful if you create a new vim session in a short time after you close one.

I know the [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) plugin, but have no idea how to use it to do this job, trying saved text state is not an option.

Comment: If you havent saved yet, `:edit!` will work

Comment: Not sure this is what you want, but you could try sth like this: https://0x0.st/zlTN.txt
Alternatively, you may be interested in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2115/17449), and in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13004/17449).
Note that the helper functions are not needed anymore (`changenr()` and `undotree().seq_cur` should be reliable), at least if your Vim includes [8.0.1290](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1290).

Comment: Another thing I want to add—this is a non-issue for me, as I’ve never needed to “hold undo”—git makes tracking changes so much easier. Undo is a convenience, one I’m willing to lose (just a bag of files and data). Git helps make it more permanent, especially when I distribute the repo

Comment: @user938271 Thanks, very helpful. Since It's been discussed plenty in that question, I will close this question.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not everything is in a git repo, git also won't help if you have not stage your changes.