# What's the configuration used to make vim remember modifications after closing the file?

Tags: vimrc, undo-redo, spacevim

I've recently started using [SpaceVim](https://spacevim.org/) which is basically vim that comes with some extra plugins and pre-done configurations. However, it has a default behavior that bothers me... It remembers changes after closing the file. That means that if I press `u` after reopening the file I end up erasing changes that I was working on a different day. The behavior is the following:

[image]

While the text was disappearing I was pressing `u`... Is there any variable I can configure in `vim` to reverse this behavior?

Comment: you want to disable persistent undo files. Read about it at `:h 'undofile'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting to use to preserve the undo is:
`set undofile`

To disable undo file: `set noundofile`

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct question to "how can I disable this feature", but my little [undofile_warn.vim](https://github.com/arp242/undofile_warn.vim) plugin will show a warning before undoing changing from previous Vim instances, which should also solve your problem, while retaining this (IMO useful) functionality.

Also see: [Can I be notified when I'm undoing changes from the undofile?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2115/51), which also has some other solutions, but my plugin has been working well for me personally for the last 7 years.

But if you want to disable it altogether you can use `set noundofile`, as Vivian's answer already mentions.