# How to disable the ability to undo even after restarting Neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I made some changes in files using Neovim. I close the vim and terminal. When I open the file again with Neovim, I am still able to undo the last things I changed before closing the terminal. I simply want to disable this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the configuration used to make vim remember modifications after closing the file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37532/whats-the-configuration-used-to-make-vim-remember-modifications-after-closing-t)

Comment: Looking forward to the question "I just realized I botched my config up on Friday. How can I undo last week's changes?"

Comment: Fair question, but WHY?

Comment: @sugamsharma, Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further. Otherwise maybe could you accept a solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the following line to your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file:

```
set noundofile
```

Or if you are using a `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` file:

```lua
vim.o.undofile = false
```

If `undofile` option is set the undo tree is persisted in files otherwise it is lost.

More information with: `:help 'undofile'`