# How to prevent Vim from clearing history?

Tags: buffers, undo-redo

Is there way to prevent Vim from clearing history after exiting Vim?

I want to be able to see the changes I made, while I am using [Gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/) (or [UndoTree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)), even though I quit vim and the terminal and come back to the same file later on?

Comment: See: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-can-i-use-the-undofile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `undotree` setting for this - `:h undotree.txt`, `:h undodir` and `:h presistent_undo`.

I have it like so:

```
if has('persistent_undo')
  if exists('$SUDO_USER')
    " don't create root-owned files
    set noundofile
  else
    set undodir=~/.local/tmp/vim/undo//
    " keep undo files out of the way
    set undodir+=~/.vim/tmp/undo//
    set undodir+=.    
    " actually use undo files
    set undofile
  endif
endif
```

Despite the check for sudo user to not create a undo file owned by root, this sets few dirs for Vim to create undofile (first available will be used). Also this has `set undofile` to make sure undofile will be used.

I just checked on some config file with UndoTree and there are changes made 11 days ago and I'm sure I did reboot my laptop in between at least 4 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot @grodzik! Do you know how long it keeps the undofile?

Comment: I would guess that forever - it says persistent ;)

Comment: That makes sense! 

Comment: FYI: The code @grodzik provided works both for UndoTree **and** Gundo.