# How to delete a file from within a vimscript?

Tags: macos, vimrc

I'm trying to automate cleaning up old vim undo files that are for files that have since been deleted.

So far I've created a new vim script at `~/.vim/autoload/cleanupUndos.vim`:

```
function cleanupUndos#clean()
    let undofiles = systemlist('ls /Users/me/.vim/undodir/')

    for undofile in undofiles
        let filepath = substitute(undofile, "%", "/", "g")
        if empty(glob(filepath))
            echo "File doesn't exist, deleting undofile for " filepath
            let deleteresult = delete(undofile)
            echo deleteresult == 0 ? 'SUCCEEDED' : 'FAILED'
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

And in my `~/.vimrc` I've set the undofile and undodir and added the autocmd for running the cleanup:

```
set undofile
set undodir=/Users/me/.vim/undodir
autocmd VimEnter * :call cleanupUndos#clean()
```

The problem is that when I open vim, it immediately prints `FAILED` and none of the files ever get deleted. I can run the `delete(filename)` command in a vim session and it works, but it doesn't seem to work when run from the script. I've tried [different ways of deleting files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430646/182202) with no success.

**How can I delete files from within a vimscript?**

(I'm running Vim version 7.4.8056 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.)

Comment: Can you try using full(absolute) path of `ls` binary , you can find it with `which` command

Comment: @Ten-Coin Thanks for the suggestion, but the `ls` command is working fine. I can see the full file paths being printed in the `echo` line. It's finding the right files, it just isn't deleting them.

Comment: Just checking, are you sure about permissions?

Comment: @Ten-Coin what permissions exactly? I have rw permissions on cleanupUndos.vim, rw on all the undofiles, and rwx on the undodir.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape file name since it contains "/". Try using

```
delete(fnameescape(filepath))
```

Check `:help fnameescape` for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ankit, but even after adding `fnameescape`, it is still failing to delete.

Comment: @Logan could you show the output of the `echo` command that you mentioned in your earlier comment?

Comment: `File doesn't exist, deleting undofile for /Users/me/tmp/tmp.txt` Then I press Enter and it replaces that text with `FAILED`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend tpope's [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) for executing all these kinds of UNIX shell commands, which includes `Delete`, `Move`, `Rename`, `Chmod`, to just name a few of them. To install it, visit this [page](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/eunuch-vim)